# 410 Gone error after WordPress update

Tags: wordpress, apache, dreamhost, http-status-code-410, http-status

Last night I updated [joinordie.com](http://joinordie.com) to WP 3.9.1 via the dashboard and today the site gives a 410 Gone error. I'm not certain that the issue is WordPress but it seems likely due to the timing, right?

> **Gone** The requested resource / is no longer available on this server
>   and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to
>   this resource.

The site was fine right before the update. It only uses 2 plugins: [Disqus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) and [Widget Logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/). I doubt they're the issue. What can I do to fix this? I can't get into wp-admin because it's 410 gone too. Should I try to manually reinstall WordPress via FTP? What could cause this error and how do I fix it?

**Update:** I just noticed that the error occurs on another (non-WP) site for the same FTP user.

Comment: I visited joinordie.com and it was working for me. Is the 410 error happening on a specific page?

Comment: disable all plugins. if you can't do that by wp-admin, rename your plugins folder to "plugins.hold". login into your website and active them again, one by one. Check your folder and file permissions on FTP. Let me know if works :)

Comment: @WillThresher It affects all pages for me in FF and Chrome. Which browser did you use? FF showed the errors last night but I thought if was a freak thing. Chrome now shows the errors too.

Comment: Thanks @LucasHaas. I tried renaming to the folder but no dice. I'm still getting 410 gone on every page including wp-admin. I may not be WordPress. See my update above.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 34.0.1847.131 - when I switched over to FF 29 however I did get the 410 error. If you can get to it via FTP - try erasing all the content of your .htaccess file (copy it just in case) - the hope is Wordpress will re-write your .htaccess file

Comment: I wrote a post with the [http status code 410 in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44803538/1250185)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Will Thresher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23659662/770127#comment36342446_23659662) I was able to discover the exact problem. In the `.htaccess` on both those sites there was code for [Perishable Press's 2010 user agent blacklist](http://perishablepress.com/2010-user-agent-blacklist/). I removed that code and it worked fine. So the answer is to check `.htaccess` and remove any problematic rules.

Comment: Great! .htaccess can be a real pain sometimes, glad it's figured out.

Comment: htaccess wasn't the problem for me. I changed the permalink structure to basic and this fixed the problem