# Comments Not Posting on Wordpress - Blank Page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a theme (http://lillykauffman.com/wordpress/2017/06/26/hello-world/), which I've done before, but if you try to post a comment, you will be redirected to a blank page.  This also happens on the other WP themes such as twentysixteen.  Here is the code I have on wp-comments-post.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Handles Comment Post to WordPress and prevents duplicate comment posting.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( 'POST' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    $protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
    if ( ! in_array( $protocol, array( 'HTTP/1.1', 'HTTP/2', 'HTTP/2.0' ) ) ) {
        $protocol = 'HTTP/1.0';
    }

    header('Allow: POST');
    header("$protocol 405 Method Not Allowed");
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    exit;
}

/** Sets up the WordPress Environment. */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

nocache_headers();

$comment = wp_handle_comment_submission( wp_unslash( $_POST ) );
if ( is_wp_error( $comment ) ) {
    $data = intval( $comment->get_error_data() );
    if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {
        wp_die( '<p>' . $comment->get_error_message() . '</p>', __( 'Comment Submission Failure' ), array( 'response' => $data, 'back_link' => true ) );
    } else {
        exit;
    }
}

$user = wp_get_current_user();

/**
 * Perform other actions when comment cookies are set.
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 *
 * @param WP_Comment $comment Comment object.
 * @param WP_User    $user    User object. The user may not exist.
 */
do_action( 'set_comment_cookies', $comment, $user );

$location = empty( $_POST['redirect_to'] ) ? get_comment_link( $comment ) : 
$_POST['redirect_to'] . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;

/**
 * Filters the location URI to send the commenter after posting.
 *
 * @since 2.0.5
 *
 * @param string     $location The 'redirect_to' URI sent via $_POST.
 * @param WP_Comment $comment  Comment object.
 */
$location = apply_filters( 'comment_post_redirect', $location, $comment );

wp_safe_redirect( $location );
exit;
```

I don't know why this isn't working since it's straight from WP, and other people online had this error because their file was blank, which is not my case.  And all of this code looks to be in order.  My MySQL version is 5.7 so that shouldn't be the issue, but at this point, I don't even know what's wrong anymore - the code, the installation, my hosting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** My host advertises full blog, comment and discussion board functionality but I contacted them and they were like, "not really."  Apparently they don't support comments or email sending.  What a waste.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: the website returns a HTTP 410 status code (401 Gone) This usually has something to do with `.htaccess` could you post that for us?

Comment: Check the PHP error log and see if there's something weird there. Where do you get redirected?

Comment: @FMashiro `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: @Capsule I get redirected to wp-comments-post.php, but it's the blank page.  There's even a blank source when I view it from the front end, so maybe it's not loading correctly?  Also I can't find the PHP error log for my host, and I might not have it at my disposal, unfortunately.

Comment: @Lilly what if you make your last rewrite rule this: `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
` ?

Comment: @Lily first try to check by back up or by deleting `.htaccess`. and check its working well or not.

Comment: @FMashiro That doesn't work with my since my test side is under /wordpress - it redirects back to my main site

Comment: You probably get an error 500. You would likely get a 404 if it was a rewrite issue. Btw, if I remember well, wordpress doesn't *need* rewrite rules to run. the URLs are prettier with them tho.

Comment: @Capsule Look at the first comment, I tried it and it returns a 410. @Lilly you also have a RewriteBase which might be the reason why it fails,since it would go to `/wordpress/wordpress/index.php` Do you mind trying?

Comment: @mayank If I make the file blank or delete it, my host gives a 404 message.

Comment: @FMashiro Yes, I did try before I wrote my last comment.  Sorry I didn't specify that.  It just redirected back to my main site.

Comment: @Lily comment extra code from the .htaccess file and `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>` only paste this and check.

Comment: @mayank unfortunately that yielded a 500 error

Comment: @Lily revert all and check in your console. Is there any error like 500 server not found.!

Comment: @mayank Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to do that

Comment: @Lily i have tried to comment on your blog and its redirected to blank page with the error code 410 status code. please check your file is there or not.

Comment: @Lily if you have added any plugin please remove it and than check

Comment: @Lilly, can you enable [debug parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) `wp-config.php`, it could help to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look your problem page with inspect manager, you can see that your problem is a 410 code error.
[image: 410 error image]

> **410 Gone**
>
> Indicates that the resource requested is no longer available at the server and will not be available again.

This error can occur in several ways.

Here it's the list of somes checkpoint to help you to find the problem:

#### **1.** *Enable debugging in wp-config.php*

```
     // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
     define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
     
     // Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
     define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

     // Enable display of errors and warnings 
     define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
     @ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

And test to know if your error appear. You'll be able to fix it quickly.

#### **2.** *Reset permalink*

Don't know why but, sometimes, Wordpress have some weird error du to a old permalink.

I suggest you to

- Going to `Settings -> Permalinks`
- Switch permalink setting,
- Save,
- Replace it to your current configuration,
- save it again.

#### **3.** *Deactivating all plugins.*

if its works, activate plugin one by one to be able to detect which one create this error.

#### **4.** *Refresh your .htaccess*

place the basic wordpress `.htaccess`. Sometimes, some plugins change rules from your `.htaccess` and provoke many redirections error.

#### **5.** *Switch your theme for a default theme without modification*

It help you to know if a custom rules in your theme create this error.

#### **6.** *Re-upload the wp-admin and wp-includes from fresh install*

#### **7.** *Reset folders write/read permissions*

you can read [Changing File permissions in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) to help you to know what you should change and what it should do.

#### **8.** *ULTIMATELY, Create a fresh install of Wordpress*